# Is there anyway to console the value which is present inside here?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

**Services.ts**
I need to findout the data present inside this API.How do we console this one?

```
   findCourseCategories() {
      return this.http.get(`/api/course-categories`)
        .pipe(
          map(res => res["categories"])
        );
    }
```

Comment: See this: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the tap :

```
import { map, tap} from 'rxjs';

findCourseCategories() {
  return this.http.get(`/api/course-categories`)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('categories: ', JSON.stringify(data))),
      map(res => res["categories"])
    );
}
```